# Uninitialized Pointers in g++ vs MS c++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, g++, gcc-warning

Recently, I read a coding example that explained the following would cause a compiler error in Visual Studio:

```cpp
int* pointer1;
*pointer1 = 10;
```

The author claimed that since `pointer1` is uninitialized before being dereferenced, the following error occurs in Visual Studio:

> C4700: uninitialized local variable "pointer1" used

And it does. This scenario makes sense.

However, if I use the exact same code and compile with g++, no compiler error occurs and I'm free to use `pointer1` in any normal fashion.

Why the difference? Is g++ assigning an address to `pointer1` before initialization?

Comment: Are you turning warnings on for the **g++** compiler?  The code is an example of *undefined behavior (no diagnostic required)*.  Visual Studio is politely providing a diagnostic.  GCC g++ can provide a diagnostic, if you enable the warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Try to pass `-Wuninitialized -Werror` to gcc. Additionally `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` may help identifying execution paths which leave the variable uninitialized.

On a side note: dereferencing uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. This means compiler may but does not have to diagnose it. The full blame is on developer.

Comment: It may be worth adding that you usually want to enable more compiler warnings than just this one, so your compiler tells you if you're about to shoot yourself in the foot. For gcc or clang, you probably want `-Wall` and maybe `-Wextra` enabled. [gcc documentation on warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: That's a great suggestion!  It seems to me a more aggressive warning schema would be the default?!  My feet are already full of hole!  Thanks!